# How to let stop the user from entering only "()" and outputting only "()" after that

Tags: python, input, output

I am fairly new at python so I don't know much about it :/. However, this is my code:

```
valid_chars = "0123456789-+/*ans() \n";
while True:
    x = "x="
    y = input(" >> ")
    x += y
    def ans():
        return z
    def ans():
        try:
            return z
        except NameError:
            return 0 # appropriate value
    if any(c not in valid_chars for c in y):
        print("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
        continue
    try:
        exec(x)
    except (SyntaxError, ZeroDivisionError, NameError, TypeError, ValueError):
        print ("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
    else:
        z = x
        print(x)
```

This works, but not perfectly. If the user types "()", it will output "()". How do I stop it from outputting "()" and say "WARNING: Invalid Equation"? Thanks in advance!

Update:

Would it work if I use the "if not" function? Example:

```
if not(y == "()"):
    continue
except:
    print ("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
```

I know that this does not work but how can I fix it or are there any better ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you fix the indentation of the code in your question? At a minimum, the first `except` needs to be indented at the same level as the `try` statement before it, but it's not clear to me if there are other errors.

Comment: ok, sure I will fix it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `raise`, as follows:

```
if y == '()':
     raise SyntaxError
```

Here is your edited code:

```
valid_chars = "0123456789-+/*ans() \n";
while True:
    x = "x="
    y = input(" >> ")
    x += y
    def ans():
        try:
            return z
        except NameError:
            return 0 # appropriate value
    if y == '()':
        print ("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
        break
    if any(c not in valid_chars for c in y):
        print("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
        try:
            exec(x)
        except (SyntaxError, ZeroDivisionError, NameError, TypeError, ValueError):
            print ("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
            break
        else:
            z = x
            print(x)
```

Ta da! Thanks to `raise`...

Comment: Yes, just make sure you do `if statement == '()': ...` :)

Comment: Oh, hold on, got a: NameError: name 'statement' is not defined

Comment: Yeah... statement was just pseudo-code... change it to `y`

Comment: Still got error:     raise SyntaxError
  File "<string>", line None
SyntaxError: <no detail available

Comment: What python version are you using? If you are using python-2.7, I suggest changing `input` to `raw_input`. Then it might work :)

Comment: oooooh... let me run this code in my idle shell and see what I get :)

Comment: Ok, it doesn't make a difference with your version, it is just that the `raise SyntaxError` is causing that to happen. Instead, you could just `print ("WARNING: Invalid Equation")` inside your `if y == '()':`

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to put code after the `continue` statement (at the same level of indentation). Such code will never be run, since `continue` tells Python to go back to the top of the loop..

Comment: @aj8uppal I know that I could do that but the script just continues. How do you make it stop? Thanks :)

Comment: Well, the `continue` isn't even needed, but I just tried it and it did work, even with the `continue`

Comment: a break just ends the whole program though... What about if not(y == "()"): continue; except (y == "()"): print ("WARNING: Invalid Equation") or something...

Comment: @HelloWorld check your email :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48734/discussion-between-hello-world-and-aj8uppal)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a straightforward edit of your current code that makes `()` an illegal value, just as if `y` contained an illegal character.

```
valid_chars = "0123456789-+/*ans() \n";
while True:
    x = "x="
    y = input(" >> ")
    x += y
    def ans():
        try:
            return z
        except NameError:
            return 0 # appropriate value
    if y == "()" or any(c not in valid_chars for c in y): # fix is here!!!
        print("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
        continue
    try:
        exec(x)
    except (SyntaxError, ZeroDivisionError, NameError, TypeError, ValueError):
        print ("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
    else:
        z = x
        print(x)
```

In addition to adding the check for `()`, I also got rid of the duplicated definition of `ans`.

Note that this still doesn't avoid all issues where an unexpected entry for `y` gives you a value that isn't useful. For instance, if you enter `(())` you'll get a nested tuple, and if you enter `ans` (without parentheses after it), `x` will become a function object. Here's an alternative approach that simply declares invalid any result that is not an integer or floating point number.

```
valid_chars = "0123456789-+/*ans() \n";
while True:
    x = "x="
    y = input(" >> ")
    x += y
    def ans():
        try:
            return z
        except NameError:
            return 0 # appropriate value
    if any(c not in valid_chars for c in y):
        print("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
        continue
    try:
        x=eval(y)
    except (SyntaxError, ZeroDivisionError, NameError, TypeError, ValueError):
        print ("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
    else:
        if isinstance(x, (int, float)):    # verify that we got a number
            z = x
            print(x)
        else:
            print("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
```

Another note: Is there a reason to use a function for `ans` rather than just a variable, like `z`? You could initialize `z` to 0 before starting the loop, and then have simpler code afterwards:

```
z = 0 # initialize z
valid_chars = "0123456789-+/*() \nz" # z is only letter that is valid
while True:
    x = "x="
    y = input(" >> ")
    x += y

    # no ans function needed

    if any(c not in valid_chars for c in y):
        print("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
        continue
    else:
        if isinstance(x, (int, float)):
            z = x # this line does all the work of setting up `z` for later calls
            print(x)
        else:
            print("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
```

Note that in general, it's usually not a good idea to use `exec` or `eval` on untrusted input. If you strictly limit what will be evaluated, you might be safe (as I think you are so far with the your code), but if you are at all careless you might have somebody submit an "equation" that deletes your hard drive or does something else malicious. Rather than trying to out-think an attacker and forbidding all such abuses, you might have an easier time creating your own parser that only accepts the limited amount of syntax that you want it to handle.

Comment: Ok, I will look into other things to replace "exec" "eval", thanks